# How to reset specific rows of hidden state (at which sequences have ended) in following RNN example of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have a batch of sequences (say 50) of input elements having variable lengths. I am feeding all elements from all batches at time `T` as input and comparing network output with all elements from all batches at time `T+1`.

Whenever some sequences from the batch are finished, I replace them with next sequences and reset corresponding hidden state.

Following is the pseudo-code to represent what I am doing roughly.

```
# elements at time T
x = placeholder(shape=[batch_size, n_features])
# elements at time T+1
y = placeholder(shape=[batch_size, n_features])
```

I have defined RNN unit as follows:

```
def RNN_unit(previous_hidden_state, x):
r  = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, Wr) + br)
z  = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, Wz) + bz)
h_ = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(x, Wx) + tf.matmul(previous_hidden_state, Wh) * r)
current_hidden_state = tf.mul((1 - z), h_) + tf.mul(previous_hidden_state, z)
return current_hidden_state
```

And using it as:
    hidden_state = RNN_unit(hidden_state, x)
    output = activation_function(hidden_state)

```
cost = loss_function(output, y)
train_step = some_optimizer.minimize(cost)
```

Now when I feed the network in following fashion

```
while data_is_available:
    x_batch = elements at time T
    y_batch = elements at time T+1

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:x_batch, y:y_batch})

    # Now I want to reset those hidden states in a batch
    # for which sequence is finished at time step T+1

    # CODE TO RESET THOSE ROWS OF HIDDEN STATE HERE...
```

When I try something like following:

```
for rowindex in rows_to_be_reset:
    hidden_state_matrix = sess.run(hidden_state)
    hidden_state_matrix[rowindex, :] = 0
    hidden_state = tf.constant(hidden_state_matrix)
```

But as `hidden_state` is dependent on `x` placeholder, I am unable to fetch it's value matrix without feeding actual `x_batch` instances.

I know I can do it in `theano` but not sure how to do the same in `tensorflow`.
How should I define a node of `hidden_state` in such case?

Comment: Are you feeding in previous_hidden_state from a placeholder?

Comment: @jasekp previous hidden state is same as next hidden state (I essentially modify current hidden state with GRU unit) please see updated code.

Comment: I think the solution may lie in [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#dynamic_rnn). It should allow you to pass things in through placeholders and has some fancy options. I think it could be what you want.

Comment: I have created my own RNN_unit which involves transformations of hidden_state using the weights learned so far. In tensorflow's built-in RNNCells, I am unable to figure out how to make use of weights? [updated my question to include RNN_unit definition]